# Enabled Language fallback, creating the first version of new lang has empty fields( Sitecore 9.3)

Tags: multilingual

While trying to create the first version of `Spanish(Ver 1)`, I see all the fields are empty, it doesn't populate the same values from the eng version.

`Enabled enableItemLanguageFallback = "true" in the site name="website" in sitecore.config`.

Added the fallback language as en for Spanish

[image]

[image]

Is there any change I need to make to enable the fallback for the first version to be en?

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, I think you are skipping enable version level fallback, which I mentioned at the end of this answer.

To enable site-level language fallback:

Open `\App_Config\Sitecore\Sitecore.config` and set the following attributes to `true`:

- enableItemLanguageFallback
- enableFieldLanguageFallback

**You must enable the attributes on the shell and on each of the relevant websites. Use patch files, don't make changes directly.**

```
<sites>
      <site name="shell">
        <patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
      </site>
      <site name="website">
        <patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
      </site>
</sites>
```

Now you must specify the language that you want it to fall back to. The fallback language specified on a language definition item applies to all the fields and items that have language fallback enabled. That you have also done as mentioned in your question.

On all the individual items or item templates where you want to use language fallback, **you must enable item-level fallback**.

- In the content tree go to the relevant item.
- To enable language fallback on a template, go to the relevant template and click the `_Standard Values` item.
- In the Advanced section, select `Enable Item fallback`.
  [image]

You can `enable field-level fallback` as well.

***Enable versioned field-level fallback*** – to enable language fallback for only the current language version of the field.

To allow different fallback settings for the same field in different languages (versioned fallback), in the `Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config` file, you must set the configuration setting `LanguageFieldFallback.AllowVaryFallbackSettingsPerLanguage to true`. However, this degrades performance considerably.

Refer to the document for more details: [Enable and set up language fallback](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/enable-and-set-up-language-fallback.html)

Hope it helps you.